# Select best set of binary variables for clustering known sample labels

Tags: r, clustering, categorical-data, feature-selection, binary-data

I have a set of samples, for which I know the "true groups". For this samples I have about 200 binary variables, I would like to know a method to select the subset of variables, that gives me a clustering as closer as possible of my known groups.

```
# sample labels
labelColors2 <-c("black", "black","black","black","black","black",     "blue","blue","blue","blue","green", "green",
"red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red","red")
# data matrix
library(RCurl)
x <- getURL("https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/10712588/binMatrix")
tab3 <- read.table(text = x)
colLab <- function(n) {
if(is.leaf(n)) {
a <- attributes(n)
#clusMember a vector designating leaf grouping
#labelColors <- colors # a vector of colors for the above grouping
labCol <- labelColors2[clusMember[which(names(clusMember) == a$label)]]
attr(n, "nodePar") <- c(a$nodePar, list(lab.col = labCol,lab.cex=0.8))
}
n
}
mclust <- hclust(dist(tab3, method ="binary"))
dhc <- as.dendrogram(mclust)
clusMember <- cutree(mclust, k=24)
clusDendro <- dendrapply(dhc, colLab)
plot(clusDendro)
```

[image: example of the true groups given by colours]

The colors should be grouped, this is my actual way to access the goodness of clustering, visually, but I would like to know a feature selection technique.

thks in advance...

updating the question, I found the    **klaR::stepclass** function, that should to what I want, or some similar implementation, but I did not find a work around yet.

```
fac <- as.factor(labelColors2)
mylda <- function(x, grouping) {
clust <- pam(dist(x, method="binary"), k=4,
    cluster.only = TRUE)
posterior <- matrix(0, 24, 4) 
colnames(posterior) <- c("black", "blue", "green", "red")
for(i in 1:nrow(posterior)) posterior[i, clust[i]] <- 1 
l <- list(class=grouping, posterior=posterior)
class(l) <- "foo"
return(l)

}
```

With the function above I can reproduce an output of my classification, similar to what **klaR::ucpm** needs, but I can't manage to run the function

```
sc_obj <- stepclass(x=tab3, grouping=fac, method="mylda", direction="forward")

Error in parse(text = x) : <text>:2:0: unexpected end of input
1: fac ~
  ^
```

Well, I think I had some improvement, I established a "fitness function", and with a random search (it is still running, I found a better clustering already

```
predict.foo <- function(x) x 
for(i in 1:1000000) {
s <- sample(1:ncol(tab3),sample(68:200,1)) 
cr <- ucpm(predict(mylda(tab3[,s], fac))$posterior, fac)$CR 
write.table(matrix(c(cr, s), nrow=1), "randonSearch.txt", append=TRUE,         row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
}
```

With this I'm monitoring the **randonSearch.txt** file with:

```
cut -d " " -f1 ../randonSearch.txt | grep 0.8
```

I already found a "Correctness Rate" of 0.833, check it out

[image]

I think there is still room for improvement, I'm thinking in a genetic algorithm...

Comment: It might be good to ask why you have the one F0_02 so close to the shared root. It might be good to ask similar questions of the 10, vs 08, and 07.  Is there any chance that the dendrogram is not robust, or that the inputs have noise that confuses the algorithm?

Comment: Hi @EngrStudent probably the histogram is not the best. The stepclass function from klaR has cross validation, but I could not figure out how to use it.

Comment: Why not use a classification (=supervised learning) algorithm instead of clustering (=unsupervised learning)? A "clustering" problem with a subset of known population memberships is, by definition, a classification problem. There are many excellent variable selection procedures in classification.

Comment: Incidentally, did you ever solve the stepwise classifier problem? Your question is the only result for that error message ;)

Comment: Hi Trevor, unfortunately I did not, I stop with my random search.

Answer (score 1):

It is hard to answer your question without knowledge of how many samples you have and how many features you want, but here is a quick and dirty solution that may work.

Draw random pairs of samples from your set and compute a derived feature vector in {-1, 1}^200, with +1 in positions where the two samples are the same and -1 where the two samples are different. Assign a label +1 if the two samples are from the same cluster and -1 if they are from different clusters. Keep drawing pairs of samples until you have a sizable number. You will now have a labeled data set of training examples.

Now run a feature selection algorithm for classification (of which there are many) for this classification problem. You might start with a simple method like using lars to fit a regression model and using the indices of the non-zero coefficients to pick you features.

Comment: If a couple of observation now become a single observation, with being in the same cluster is the label, how are the features defined?